# What does the float number indicate when using varnishtop?

Tags: varnish

I have Varnish running and I wanted to see what http response codes commonly occur. I used:

```
varnishtop -i TxStatus
```

However, I am struggling to work out what the numbers on the **left** mean? Is it number of requests?

```
list length 7

  1322.16 TxStatus       200
    60.43 TxStatus       302
     8.67 TxStatus       304
     3.14 TxStatus       500
     2.96 TxStatus       404
     0.80 TxStatus       301
     0.56 TxStatus       403
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot to find this, but never got the answer for this question. This is the only thing I found once.

It's an exponential decay of the frequency of arrival if I remember
right, think of it as a "bogo-frequency".

More details from the writer of this tool can be found [here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/lists/pipermail/varnish-misc/2008-June/016224.html).

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry I meant the numbers on the left. You should of been able to guess that as I mentioned http response codes in my question! :)

Comment: My bad. I really took a quick look at the question and didn't read it all. Updating my answer for the same :)

Comment: Thank you for digging this out. I couldn't find a description of this so called `bogo frequency`!